# Need help selecting an element from a jquery response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input element from a jquery ajax response. The default value for the hidden element is  0. But after the jquery post has been completed the hidden input value attribute gets changed to a different number(by php)

For some reason when I select the element from the data var (the response variable) and pass it into the html() function, it shows the value as 0 for the hidden input

Below is my code...

```
       $.post(url,obj_param)


           .done(function (data) {

               console.log(data);

               var thread_id = $("#thread").html(data);

               console.log(thread_id);



           });

     }
```

Here is a snippet of my html code

```
<section class="message_form">
    <form action="http://localhost/GuruCoders/index.php/messages/NewMessageThread/index" class='msg_form' id='59' method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div id="err_msg"> Please enter a message to send </div>

    <textarea name="msg" class="msg" id="59" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
    </form>


   <!-- The value returns as 0 not 55 -->
    <input type="hidden" id="thread" value="55" name="thread"/>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you should use `$("#thread").val(data);` in your js

Comment: Try `console.log(data);

var $thread = $("#thread").html(data);
var thread_id = $thread.find('input[name="thread"]').val()
console.log(thread_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all I don't know why you use `$("#thread").html(data);`..

However, if you want to **SET** the value you can use `$("#thread").val(data);` and if you want to **GET** the value you can use `$("#thread").val();`.